# How to restyle GeoField's proximity filter controls?

Tags: 7, views, location

**Background**
I am using the modules: geocoder geofield addressfield geophp ip_geoloc libraries to create a store locator view. The user can search the available stores using an exposed GeoField proximity filter.

**Question**
How can I restyle the GeoField's proximity filter controls? I would like to change the edit box for distance to a select with fixed values, and hide the distance units select defaulting it to miles. 
[image: Screen shot showing standard proximity filter controls]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue with editing the exposed form. Form alter is not the right way to go though. You'll need to use element info alter. Take a look at this [custom module](https://gist.github.com/cojomojo/cc61f11efe2ae4230cda) I threw together for editing the geofield proximity search. You can see what I did, and add/modify functionalities for your needs (although I think i did exactly what you wanted).

Comment: I used cojomojo's module as a starting point, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if (($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') &&  ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-your-view')) {
    $form['proximity']['default_radius']['#type'] = 'select';
    $form['proximity']['default_radius']['#options'] = array(10, 20, 30);
    $form['proximity']['radius_unit']['#type'] = 'item';
  }
}
```